# Fermi/Bose gases

Tags: statistics, order-statistics, descriptive-statistics, statistical-mechanics

Knowing that $$\Omega = -\frac{2}{3}\frac{gVm^{\frac{3}{2}}}{2^{\frac{1}{2}}\pi^{2}h^{3}} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{z^{\frac{3}{2}}dz}{z^{\frac{z-\mu}{T}}\pm1}  $$ is the thermodynamic potential for Bose Fermi particle gas and $$ \Omega = -\frac{2}{3} E,$$ where E is total energy of gas. The final equation is $$PV = \frac{2}{3}E,$$where we know that $$\Omega = -PV$$ My question is how to prove that $\Omega=-PV$. I found one suggestion : to use Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions.

Comment: Which "thermodynamic potential" are you referring to? Is it the grand potential?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry for my expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this fact: From
$$d\Omega = -SdT-PdV-Nd\mu$$
we know that
$$-P=\left( \frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial V} \right)_{T,\ \mu}$$
You don't need Euler's theorem.

Comment: But if I derivate Omega by V, the result will be -P=-(2/3)E.

Comment: @MariusMihaiLionte No, notice the $V$ in the numerator of $\Omega$. This is an exercise of calculus...